# Как на php сделать выбор цвета в зависимости какой формат файла

Tags: php

Подскажите пожалуйста как реализовать функцию, если есть в папке файл **exls** то цвет желтый, если есть любой другой файл независимо если ли exls то зелёный цвет. Спасибо.

```
   $dirm=  $row['id'];
    $dir = "uploads_v/$dirm/"; // Папка с изображениями
           $files = glob("$dir/*.*"); 
        if (empty($files)) 
            { 
              $color = ""; 
            }else{
        foreach($files as $v){
          $color = "Green"; 
        }
        }
```

Comment: Вы для экселевских файлов два цвета хотите?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```php
$row['id'] = 'img'; // Для примера
$dirm=  $row['id'];
$dir = "uploads_v/$dirm/"; // Папка с изображениями
$files = glob("$dir/*.*");
if (empty($files))
{
    $color = "";
}else{
    $num = 0; // Ставим триггер
    foreach($files as $v){ // Перебираем массив
        $Type = pathinfo($v); // Получает данные файла
        if ($Type['extension'] != 'exls') { // Если файл тип НЕ exls, то... (Если надо по имени проверять, то вместо $Type['extensions'] используйте $Type['filename']
            $num = '1'; // То меняем триггер
        }
    }
    if ($num == '1'){ // Если триггер равен 1 (Есть другие файлы, кроме exls
        $color = 'green'; // Ставим зелёный цвет
    } else { // Если триггер не равен 1 (Нет других файлов)
        $color = 'yellow'; // Ставим жёлтый цвет.
    }
}
```